# Angular advanced searchbox doesn't display suggestedValues

Tags: angularjs, advanced-search

I use [Angular advanced searchbox](https://github.com/dnauck/angular-advanced-searchbox) to create a search box.But when adding `suggestedValues` into scope `availableSearchParams` it doesn't display suggestions and my modal get undefined.Please let me know what went wrong.

**Scripts load order**

```
angular-advanced-searchbox.min.css
angular-advanced-searchbox-tpls.min.js
angular-advanced-searchbox.min.js
app.js // contain app module
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-10">
        <nit-advanced-searchbox ng-model="searchParams"  parameters="availableSearchParams" placeholder="Search..."></nit-advanced-searchbox>
        <pre><code>{{searchParams}}</code></pre>
    </div></div>
```

**App.Js**

```
$scope.availableSearchParams = [
    { key: "team", name: "Team", placeholder: "filter by team", restrictToSuggestedValues: true, suggestedValues: ['Berlin', 'London', 'Paris'] },{ key: "testtype", name: "TestType", placeholder: "filter by test type",restrictToSuggestedValues: true, suggestedValues: ['Smoke', 'Regression', 'Benchmark'] }, { key: "text", name: "Text", placeholder: "filter by text" } ];

$scope.$on('advanced-searchbox:modelUpdated', function (event, model) {
                          console.log(model);
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You must include ui.bootstrap in your module, before angular-advanced-searchbox:

```
angular.module('SensacionalApp', [
'ngMaterial',
'ui.bootstrap',
'angular-advanced-searchbox'
]);
```